# Command defined in `figure` environment visible from outside?

Tags: environments

I had understood `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` to define an [environment](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-whatenv), and that

> An environment puts its content inside a TeX group, so that commands
> used inside the environment don’t “leak out” — the `monoblock`
> environment, above, restricts its effect to its own contents (the
> stuff between the `\begin{monoblock}` and `\end{monoblock}`), which is
> just what you need for this sort of thing.

But when I compile (`pdflatex`) the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \newlength{\thisFigWidth}
        \setlength{\thisFigWidth}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \newlength{\thisFigWidth}
    \setlength{\thisFigWidth}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \thisFigWidth already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Comment: More precisely, local definitions do not leak out, but global definitions definitely do leak out.  `\newlength` is inherently global.  Try `\dimen0` through `\dimen9` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single `\newlength{\thisFigWidth}` in the document preamble and set the length in the `figure` environment. According to TeX's scoping rule the *setting* to the register will be forgotten as soon as the environment ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{comment}

\newlength{\thisFigWidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \setlength{\thisFigWidth}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \setlength{\thisFigWidth}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\thisFigWidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You might want to provide a default value for the register based on the text width. In this case do something like

```
\newlength{\thisFigWidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\thisFigWidth}{0.5\textwidth}}
```

Doing it at begin document ensures that the exact `\textwidth` is considered (in the preamble it doesn't necessarily have the final value).

---

Why don't `\newlength` instruction respect scoping rules? Because `\newlength` allocates a new register (there's a finite number of them) and we don't want that the same register is allocated twice, because the value stored in it would become unpredictable. Thus `\newlength` instructions are *global*. But you don't need to allocate a new register at each `figure` environment: just one suffices.